# Binding SKShape node to the CGPathGetCurrentPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I try to bind SKShapeNode to CGPathGetCurrentPoint of my circle. But it seems that path is not moving.

```
    CGPoint d;
...
myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(myPath, NULL, 0,0, 60, 10, M_PI*2, YES);

 arc = [SKShapeNode node];
 arc.path = myPath;
...
[self  addChild:arc];
```

Here everything is OK. Then I connect my ball to the arc

```
ball = [SKShapeNode node];
ball.path = ballPath.CGPath;
[self addChild:ball];
...
d = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(arc.path);
 ball.position =  CGPointMake(d.x, d.y);
```

In  `touchesMoved` I placed rotating code for my arc

```
arc.zRotation+=angleRadians*4;
d = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(arc.path);
 ball.position =  CGPointMake(d.x, d.y);
```

And nothing happens. I want ball attach to arc current point and move with it.

Comment: what is angleRadians set to? and have you actually instantiated the ball node somewhere in your code?

Comment: When I run the app everything is OK. Ball placed on the right position. But when I rotate the arc ball stay on the previous position and don't follow arc currentPoint. it's seems like the path don't move. I don't understand what it is.

Comment: @user2277872 I tested differnt variations and now I exactly know that the path don't move. Because when I added a line my ball changed position. But don't rotate with arc. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the shape node will change when you change the contents of the CGPath, you'd have to re-assign or perhaps even create a new version of the CGPath and assign it again if you want the shape node to change its shape.

Comment: It seems that you are mistaken on what makes `CGPathGetCurrentPoint`. `CGPathGetCurrentPoint` return the last point added to the path. So if you don't change the path, you will always get the same result.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Maybe you know how I can redraw new CGPath from SKShapeNode?